# Unable to load repositories in Tex Live manager

Tags: packages, texlive, repositories

It shows an error `No backend` and closes the manager on clicking "OK". I tried loading different repositories but it was the same. I was wondering maybe I should install the newer version of the manager? It has barely been two months since I first installed TexLive. It is showing up as Unknown for up to date. Will installing new version delete the packages I have already installed?

Comment: Normally TeXLive installs side by side and thus does not touch the old installation. You can have a look at https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html to see if your system can update. I'd normally update.

Comment: I'd also like to know exactly what you mean by `TeX Live manager`? I normally use the command line version called `tlmgr`. If I set my TeXLive to use `TL2021` and use `tlmgr` to update it I get the following message: `tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2021) is older than remote repository (2022).`

Comment: @daleif TeX Live Manager is how it is shown when I search it in start menu. I installed through .exe file and not through command line

Comment: That means you are on windows (you sis not mention). You are seeing the GFX version of `tlmgr` then. You also have `tlmgr` on the commandline. It is automatically installed. As mentioned on the `upgrade` page I linked to, one cannot upgrade TL on windows. You will need to reinstall.

Comment: If I run the manager on my Linux system in gui mode, and I accept to update it just stops and gives me a message on the command line. That, of course does not help you much when you start it from a menu.

Comment: @dalief I'll have to keep the older tex live manager as well? Will deleting it cause all the installed packages to get deleted as well? Do I have to reinstall all the packages after new Tex live manager installation?